# How to mount HTMLElement directly in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I'm using some external code that returns an HTML element, and it'd be nice to embed it without having to manage the loading and everything via JavaScript (i.e. `appendChild`/`removeChild`). Right now I'm using `{@html element.outerHTML}`, but this seems inelegant to make the round trip to an HTML string:

```html
<script>
  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  async function someCall() {
    await sleep(1000);
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerText = "hello!";
    console.log(p);
    return p;
  }

  let data = someCall();
</script>

<div>
  {#await data}
    <p>Loading data...</p>
  {:then result}
    {@html result.outerHTML}
  {/await}
</div>
```

What I'm looking for might be something like

```html
<div>
  {#await data}
    <p>Loading data...</p>
  {:then result}
    {result}
  {/await}
</div>
```

but this doesn't work (since it string-ifies the element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bind:this to append HTML

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    let elem;
    
    onMount(async () => {
      await sleep(1000);
      const p = document.createElement("p");
      p.innerText = "hello!";
      elem.appendChild(p) 
    });
</script>

<div bind:this={elem}> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this.

```
<script>
  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  async function someCall() {
    await sleep(1000);
    return `<p>hello</p>`;
  }

  let data = someCall();
</script>

<main>
    <div>
  {#await data}
    <p>Loading data...</p>
  {:then result}
    {@html result}
  {/await}
</div>
</main>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-sea-mfcx5?file=/App.svelte:0-336