# Rendering a div node created with d3.js in svelte?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svelte, sveltekit

I created a table in d3.js and return it as a `div.node()` and I am trying to render it in svelte.
It's created with fetched data so I wrap it inside an sveltes asynchronous await syntax:

```
<div>
    {#await fetched}
    <p>...waiting</p>
    {:then result}
        {@html result}
    {/await}
</div>
```

where fetched is the result of the following:

```
function getData() 
    {
        return fetch("path").then(d => tabulate(d.json(), ['col', 'col2']));
    }
    let fetched = getData();
```

However, what is returned on the page is  `[object HTMLDivElement]`
instead of the actual table. The docs say it needs to be standalone HTML, I rendered it in a file and it worked.
Should I create the element first in svelte and then select it instead?
It works if I select a pre-existing div.

The accompanying d3.js function full credit to [jfreels](https://gist.github.com/jfreels/6733593):

```
    function tabulate(data, columns) {
        const div = d3.create("div")
        
        let table = div.append('table')
        let thead = table.append('thead')
        let tbody = table.append('tbody');

        // append the header row
        thead.append('tr')
        .selectAll('th')
        .data(columns).enter()
        .append('th')
            .text(function (column) { return column; });

        // create a row for each object in the data
        let rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('tr');

        // create a cell in each row for each column
        let cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function (row) {
            return columns.map(function (column) {
            return {column: column, value: row[column]};
            });
        })
        .enter()
        .append('td')
            .text(function (d) { return d.value; });

        return div.node();
}
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66917187/how-to-mount-htmlelement-directly-in-svelte) solves it with `{@html result.outerHTML}` while there's no better answer (or I don't see if/why this would be better https://svelte.dev/repl/118b7d4540c64f8491d10a24e68948d7?version=3.12.1)

Comment: Ok, would for example be better if the element had event listeners https://svelte.dev/repl/232b0d0c9fdc49f9931da7cb81a55274?version=3.12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is a DOM element, not HTML; but since it is already a fully functional element, it is not necessary to write it as HTML and make the browser re-parse it. As Corrl noted, that would also cause all event listeners to be lost.

You can easily attach the node using e.g. an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action):

```js
const append = (node, child) => node.append(child);
```

```html
<div>
    {#await fetched}
        <p>...waiting</p>
    {:then result}
        <div use:append={result} />
    {/await}
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thank you all very much! If you don't mind, I have been looking for some more detailed documentation (I did the whole tutorial) to the "event:" bindings we can use for different components but found the docs outside of the tutorial to be a little sparse for a beginner.

Comment: @Olli What do you mean? Events are added with `on:event` syntax.

Comment: sorry, I meant things like "use:append={result}" I've learned about "things" like that in the tutorial but I have not found much in the docs.

Comment: It's called an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action). That is simply a function that gets passed two arguments, the first is the current DOM node, the second is whatever you pass in, in this case `{result}`. The function can optionally return an object with `update` and `destroy` functions (see linked docs). There really is not much to it.

Comment: actions are just great :) I wonder, it could also be `node.replaceWith(newNode)` since there's basically no need for the container div?

Comment: @Corrl: Probably, unless that causes issues when the component is destroyed, would just test it. Though, you can even move elements to different parts of the document (see e.g. actions [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1133)) without problems.