# Using svelte actions to manipulate an html element with d3

Tags: d3.js, svelte, sveltekit

this is somewhat related to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73489607/rendering-a-div-node-created-with-d3-js-in-svelte/73498658?noredirect=1#comment129795686_73498658) where I learned a bit more about actions.

I have been trying to figure out how to work with this nifty feature but I seem to be a bit stuck in the past few hours.

In my Component I create an SVG viewbox like so:

```
<svg id="pitch" viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`} use:foo>

    </svg>
```

then drawPitch is this function:

```
function foo(node) {
        // the node has been mounted in the DOM
        let g = node.append('h1');
        g.text("This is the text I'd like to render to check that it works");
        return {
            destroy() {
                // the node has been removed from the DOM
            }
        };
    }
```

From what I've understood in the docs, the `use:foo` will pass the calling node to foo, so I thought directly appending svg elements to it should work.
Do I need to update it somehow?

[Here is a repl with reproducible code.](https://svelte.dev/repl/d5a5b3c1276f4d5d90300194af2557a9?version=3.49.0)

I get the following error:

> Missing "./types/runtime/internal/keyed_each.js" export in "svelte" package

Thank you!

Comment: ("keyed each" refers to a form of `{#each}` loop, though your code does not show any. Maybe try reinstalling packages?)

Comment: @H.B. thank you. I googled for some time and could not find a related error. this indeed makes no sense then.

Comment: By the way, if you *only* use d3 to create DOM, i would advise against using it. It incurs a lot of cost in terms of complexity due to its API. You can build SVGs using Svelte alone.

Comment: @H.B. thanks a lot, yes, I'm learning to use both. There are some things I find easier because I have some (very little) experience with d3. But in the end I hope after prototyping with d3 I can switch as much as possible to svelte. Thanks so much!

Comment: @H.B. For which type of visualizations or elements would you suggest svelte and for which type d3? 
Sorry to keep bothering you, it just feels like you are very versed in both tools and not biased toward one or the other.

Comment: Depends on how much code is involved, e.g. if d3 provides complex layout calculations or animated simulations (e.g. ) it makes sense to use that. if you were to just use d3 to dynamically build a simple DOM structure (similar to using jQuery), then I would just use Svelte instead. Chances are that you still get significant value from d3, though parts seem to be fairly modular, so you could apply something like a `d3-force` simulation without the rest of d3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the code in `foo` to start with `d3.select(node)`, and everything to work based off that. Otherwise the DOM tree generated by d3 will not be connected to your document at all. Alternatively the resulting element (`selection.node()`) has to be appended to `node` at some point.

The error sounds highly unrelated and probably would require more context.

Note: You cannot add HTML directly to SVGs, SVGs are for canvas-like vector graphics, not document layouts. If you want to insert text, use the `<text>` element.

Comment: I am so sorry, I had a typo, I have `node.append('h1')`. I will with d3.select(node) instead.

Comment: I made a repl, trying this, unfortunately no luck yet. https://svelte.dev/repl/d5a5b3c1276f4d5d90300194af2557a9?version=3.49.0

Comment: One problem is that you are adding HTML (also in your REPL the `use:foo` is missing). I amended my answer (last paragraph). See [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/663aeeb89ad54405b28309c9909c2d0d?version=3.49.0) for an example.

Comment: thanks a lot, I realized now that despite having forked the repl, my changes (experiments)  were included, (i.e. I tried other things for example without `use:foo` I am sorry for the confusion. I really appreciate your help, I'll hope to pay it forward eventually!

Comment: may I ask, why the `dominant-baseline` attribute is essential?

Comment: The `text` element will be positioned at (0, 0) by default, the baseline will be roughly at `y = 0`, this means the text contents which are *on* the baseline will be off-screen otherwise.